# Titlesting/Statusline: to differentiate empty buffer from non-empty ones

Tags: statusline

I use the following settings to have the filename in the header line before the rest of the path:

```
set titlestring=
set titlestring+=%M
set titlestring+=%(\ %t%)
set titlestring+=%(\ (%{expand('%:p:h')})%)
set titlestring+=%a
```

This results to:

```
filename.txt (path/to/the/file)
```

The problem is the empty buffer. Instead of `[No Name]`, it also contains the path to the home directory:

```
[No Name] (path/to/the/home/directory)
```

What is the way to get rid of the path to the home directory for the empty buffer?

I should probably differentiate the empty buffer from non-empty ones, but I don't know how. I know there are some functions line `bufwinnr()`, but I don't understand which one I should use here.

Comment: use a function, that checks whether `expand('%')` returns an empty string. And if not, append the path.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks, I will try it.  Typos are now corrected, sorry for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by Christian Brabandt:

```
function! SetTitlestring()
  set titlestring=
  set titlestring+=%M
  set titlestring+=%(\ %t%)
  if expand('%') != ''
    set titlestring+=%(\ (%{expand('%:p:h')})%)
  endif
  set titlestring+=%a
endfunction
autocmd! BufReadPre,FileReadPre * call SetTitlestring()
```

Comment: This function gives the same title string as the default one, with the only difference that the path in parentheses is absolute. Maybe there is a simpler way, something like `set absolutepathintitlestring`?